# Objective-C - Json for Game or is there a better way

Tags: objective-c

i have some questions about json! i hope anybody can help me!

I have created a game and now i want to bring some variables out of my Game into a json file!

So i want to ask, is it possible to bring floats and an array

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50.0, 150.0)],
            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(350.0, 300.0)],nil];
```

into a json file?!

Also i want to bring my background-images for the different levels in the json file.

Is it possible to do it with json or anybody know a better way.

It would be great if anybody could tell me. Or anybody know a good tutorial?!

Thanks

Comment: To include images (or other binary data) in JSON you need to convert the image to `NSData` then encode the data to a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to serialise the objects to move between environments, then I wouldn't bother with JSON... if you are consuming a web service or something, then they are great... if you have them in values, then I would just store them in a `plist` assuming you have no interchange.

Comment: This is a good point.  A plist has a very similar feature set to JSON as a data storage format, and iOS has a lot of built in features to work with them easily.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about the background images ... you would simply store the filename/path to the image. That way, multiple files or levels could potentially refer to the same asset.

Answer (score 0):

JSON supports hashes (dictionaries) and arrays as containers, which can contain hashes, arrays, numbers, strings and booleans within them.  So to capture that data you might have a structure like this:

```
{
  "points":[
    [50.0, 150.0],
    [350.0, 300.0]
  ]
}
```

And read it back with something like this:

```
NSArray *pointsData = [json objectForKey:@"points"];
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(
                      [[pointsData objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0],
                      [[pointsData objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]
                    )],

                    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(
                      [[pointsData objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0],
                      [[pointsData objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1]
                    )],

                    nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa supports only these type in its JSON support.

```
NSNumber (integer, float, boolean)
NSString
NSArray
NSDictionary
```

Whatever you want to save/load, you should organize your data to use only those types. Direct use of `NSValue` is not supported, so you need to make something like this.

```
NSDictionary* point = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:444f],
@"x",
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:555f],
@"y",
nil];
```

And save the dictionary.
In addition, you also can use equivalent [new literal syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) which is mainly designed for *Property List*.

```
NSDictionary* point = @{ @"x" : @444f, @"y": @555f };
```

This is equal to above example.

**CAVEAT**: All keys of `NSDictionary` must be `NSString` when you are saving the data to JSON or *Property List*.

### Consider using of Property List

If you are targeting only iOS, [*Property List*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) is always right and better choice to save/load some small amount of variables. Also Xcode will give you better editor.

Support for JSON in Cocoa is just a subset of the *Property List*, and mostly similar. So look at the Property List first, and than you will be able to use PLIST or JSON easily. (this is why there's no guidance document for JSON in Cocoa)

### Background Images

It is possible to save image data in JSON or Property List, but it is usually not recommended. Because JSON or PLIST need to load at once. This means all file content must be loaded into memory. If you put multiple images in a JSON or PLIST file, it will get bigger up to multiple megabytes easily. And iOS devices doesn't have much memory, so your program may crash.

So it is recommended to store only *path to image file* in JSON or PLIST file - as like @JoelMartinez indicates -, and load the each image file directly from the path.